# is_callable loads 'pcu2phmmr6pam3' via __autoload

Tags: php, autoload

I've got a weird problem going on. I'm developing my website localhost on a xampp server before uploading it to my host server. I finally finished the basic components of my website, so that it could load the homepage. Everything worked as planned.

So I decided to upload it to the host server, then I set the MySQL credentials, now it should work. Ehm.. no, it didn't. Empty page.

So I put on my gloves and started digging into the code with random expressions as 
`echo 'test';` so I could keep track of what was going on. It seems to run just fine until `is_callable()` was executed.

`is_callable()` should run `__autoload($class)`, so I tried `var_dump($class)`

It gave me this result:

```
string(11) "Initializer" 
string(8) "Database" 
string(14) "PageController" 
string(14) "BaseController" 
string(14) "pcu2phmmr6pam3" 
string(14) "pcu2phmmr6pam3"
```

Now, every class listed here should be there, besides the last two. I have **NO** idea where that name came from, because it's not a string I've set anywhere.

The only result Google showed me for `pcu2phmmr6pam3` was another website having a similar problem.

Now the *really* weird stuff happens, my autoload function looks like this:

```
function __autoload($class) {
    var_dump($class);
    if (file_exists(ROOT_PATH . DS . 'site' . DS . 'class' . DS . $class . '.class.php')) {
        require_once(ROOT_PATH . DS . 'site' . DS . 'class' . DS . $class . '.class.php');
    } else if (file_exists(ROOT_PATH . DS . 'site' . DS . 'controller' . DS . $class . '.class.php')) {
        require_once(ROOT_PATH . DS . 'site' . DS . 'controller' . DS . $class . '.class.php');
    } else if (file_exists(ROOT_PATH . DS . 'site' . DS . 'model' . DS . $class . '.class.php')) {
        require_once(ROOT_PATH . DS . 'site' . DS . 'model' . DS . $class . '.class.php');
    } else{
        throw new Exception('Class `' . $class . '` could not be loaded!');
    }
}
```

Every class it should load, is loaded. If I want to create a class which doesn't exist, then it throws an exception.

But with the `pcu2phmmr6pam3` 'classes' neither is the case. No exceptions were thrown, and now errors were printed on the screen, even though I've set `error_reporting(E_ALL)`

Here's the surrounding code of `is_callable()`:

```
    $controllerName = ucfirst($this->structure) . 'Controller';
    $action = strtolower(((!empty($this->uri[1]))?$this->uri[1]:'index'));

    if (is_callable(array($controllerName, $action))) {
        $controller = new $controllerName($this->uri, $this->database, $this->structure, $action, $page);
        $controller->$action();
    } else if (is_callable(array($controllerName, 'index'))) {
        $controller = new $controllerName($this->uri, $this->database, $this->structure, 'index', $page);
        $controller->index();
    } else {
        $controller = new NotfoundController($this->uri, $this->database, 'Notfound', 'index', $page);
        $controller->index();
    }
```

Last bit of information I can give you:

My localhost xampp server runs PHP 5.4.7, and my host server runs PHP 5.3.20.

---

Solved, not sure how the weird classnames appeared, if someone knows, I'd like to know why :)

Comment: Just a hint: `DS` is crap. First it exists the well-known `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`, so there is no need to invent a new and unique contant, which nobody knows, and second you can use `/` and everything will be fine. Every OS understands it. Also _never_ throw an Exception in the autoloader-callback: PHP is good in recognizing missing classes itself and you will break any subsequent registered autoloader. Last but not least: `__autoload()` is outdated for years. Use `spl_autoload_register()`.

Comment: @KingCrunch Thanks for the suggestions. `DS` is actually defined as `DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR`, but it's way shorter (and thus readable). I was aware that `/` is a good replacement but I guessed that if there is a constant named `DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR`, I'd better use it.

About Exceptions and the `spl_autoload_register()` function, I'll give it a go, hopefully with success..

Comment: So, the sql_autoload_register() still gives me a white page, with the same symptoms. That didn't fix it.

Comment: Are you sure the pcu2phmmr6pam3 output is triggered by is_callable? Might be worth checking out a debug_backtrace().

Comment: @JochemKuijpers Just to make it complete: `DS` is not more readable, because it's an acronym, whereas `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` is a _readable_ (and well known) name ;) Just said. However, regarding your problem: check, if you changed the error-settings in the correct `php.ini` (there is one for each sapi) and read the logs. Also try a search for this string over your source files. Oh, and restart your server after every change of the configuration.

Comment: @KingCrunch Problem is, localhost (where I can access php.ini and the logs) works just fine. The host is the problem, which gives me limited access to php settings. I've set `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, so that should be good right? - Still gives me no errors at all. Even without the exception in the autoloader.

Comment: @JochemKuijpers Check "display_errors"-setting too.

Comment: @KingCrunch Thanks for your help, my host server apparently hides exceptions and just terminates somehow. I've played with it all day, and it turned out I forgot to copy the last character of my MySQL password. Still doesn't explain the weird classnames, but it works now.

Comment: I have the same problem here and found that bug in the php bugtracker:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42994

Comment: @stolf Thanks, I no longer need a solution for this, but the bugreport finally made me understand why this was happening!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem calling a static method. (same with `spl_autoload_register()`)

```
function __autoload ($className) {
  echo $className."\n";
}

class ClassName {
  function functionName () {
  }
}

//calls __autoload twice with class name 'a22h1pd_t'
is_callable( array('ClassName', 'functionName') );

//doesn't call __autoload
is_callable('ClassName::functionName');
```

Looking at this minimal example it's obvious. The `static` keyword for `functionName` is missing. Adding it resolved the problem for me with both syntaxes behaving as expected.